# Solidify modifer makes to steep thickness, can we control the angle?

Tags: solidify-modifier

I need the hat brim thickness to go downward. But solidify modifier makes it, inward.
What is the solution?

Extruding makes the original face gone, I can't use that method either. The only think I can think of is to copy the brim and then connect the vertices manually.

Is there another way?

[file:drive.google.com/file/d/1IYxVjhhNdHob1kMux2Ax20ivsrzqxS-P/view?usp=sharing](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1IYxVjhhNdHob1kMux2Ax20ivsrzqxS-P/view?usp=sharing)

[image]

Comment: Change the solidify offset to +1 to make the thickness go upwards. You may need to check the 'Even' setting to get a consistant thickness.

Comment: Not working. The result is similar, the different it's steep outward.

Comment: please share the hat: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: The link you posted is just text, not a link to the file. As @moonboots says, please use https://pasteall.org/blend/.

Comment: apply the scale on the object, if not modifiers show strange behaviour... go object mode and press Ctrl+A > Scale, then reset solidify modifier values and try again...

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what you want, but you could try this:

first delete the solidify modifier, then select these:

[image]

then Shift-D -> Z -> move down as thick as you want it

[image]

select these:

[image]

bridge edge loop

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Apply the scale, lower down the thickness and it will work fine. Also it's always better to correct the normals as suggested by Chris.

[image]